# Starting a user-space program as non-root user at boot with upstart

Tags: 12.04, upstart

Is there a method to set up an upstart script to execute a user-space program ***without*** keeping root privileges, but so the user which has directory/permissions-based ownership of the program can stop/start while still having the program start at boot time?

Comment: Also, if anyone can point me to examples of upstart scripts that'd be awesome

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with sudo:

```
sudo -u lordoftime program
```

-u + username start the program as that user.

Comment: Will this also use user-space environment stuff, such as `~/.progfolder/`?

Comment: @LordofTime: As far as I read in the man page, you can use -H to set the home, and -i to start the loginshell of the user, thereby reading some configuration files. There are multiple blocks in the manpage refering to ENV, I don't like to cite complete. Read it up yourself, try it out and tell us, if you experience further problems.

Comment: Thank you! Short, gets the job done, and doesn't beat around the bush

Answer (score 1):

Problem using `su` trick with [system jobs](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#id93) the user has no control over that job. It is still a system job, despite running as given user.

Proper solution in 12.04 is using [user jobs](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#id94). Those jobs live in each user's `$HOME/.init` and are fully controllable by that user. They also do not have root powers as user job is always run as that user's credentials. Otherwise they act just as system jobs, so you can define `start on`stanzas just like system jobs.

By default, Upstart jobs have no environment set except what is defined in the job. You can circumvent that by exec'ing via `sh -l` (`exec /bin/sh -l -c "exec YOUR STUFF HERE"`).

Comment: Does this work with 11.04, the system which this is going to be in use on?

Comment: See Cookbook about enabling user jobs in prior to 12.04: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#id95 Then it should work (0.9.7 in 11.04 is about the same as 1.3 in upstream).